# turtlebot apt-get update has generated an error on minimal.launch

Tags: robotic-arm, turtlebot, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Just ran apt-get update on a turtlebot install on an odroid C1 (ARM board) running 14.04 and indigo.

robot_state_publihser version is 1.10.4

After the update running minimal.launch I get the rising notes from the turtlebot but output now contains error

```
odroid@odroid:~$ roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
... logging to /home/odroid/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101/roslaunch-odroid-1862.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://odroid:57919/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /app_manager/auto_rapp_installation: False
 * /app_manager/auto_start_rapp: 
 * /app_manager/capability_server_name: capability_server
 * /app_manager/local_remote_controllers_only: False
 * /app_manager/preferred: [{'rocon_apps/chi...
 * /app_manager/rapp_package_blacklist: []
 * /app_manager/rapp_package_whitelist: ['rocon_apps', 't...
 * /app_manager/robot_icon: turtlebot_bringup...
 * /app_manager/robot_name: turtlebot
 * /app_manager/robot_type: turtlebot
 * /app_manager/screen: True
 * /app_manager/simulation: False
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /capability_server/blacklist: ['std_capabilitie...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiBringup: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiBumper: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiCliffDetection: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiLED1: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiLED2: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiLED: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/kobuki_capabilities/KobukiWheelDropDetection: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/std_capabilities/Diagnostics: turtlebot_capabil...
 * /capability_server/defaults/std_capabilities/DifferentialMobileBase: kobuki_capabiliti...
 * /capability_server/defaults/std_capabilities/LaserSensor: turtlebot_capabil...
 * /capability_server/defaults/std_capabilities/RGBDSensor: turtlebot_capabil...
 * /capability_server/defaults/std_capabilities/RobotStatePublisher: turtlebot_capabil...
 * /capability_server/defaults/turtlebot_capabilities/TurtleBotBringup: turtlebot_capabil...
 * /capability_server/nodelet_manager_name: capability_server...
 * /capability_server/package_whitelist: ['kobuki_capabili...
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/indigo/s...
 * /description: Kick-ass ROS turtle
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/input_ports/contains: ['Digital Input',...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/input_ports/path: Input Ports
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/input_ports/remove_prefix: mobile_base_nodel...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/input_ports/timeout: 5.0
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/input_ports/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/kobuki/contains: ['Watchdog', 'Mot...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/kobuki/path: Kobuki
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/kobuki/remove_prefix: mobile_base_nodel...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/kobuki/timeout: 5.0
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/kobuki/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/contains: ['Battery', 'Lapt...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/path: Power System
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/remove_prefix: mobile_base_nodel...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/timeout: 5.0
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/contains: ['Cliff Sensor', ...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/path: Sensors
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/remove_prefix: mobile_base_nodel...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/timeout: 5.0
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/type: diagnostic_aggreg...
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/base_path: 
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/pub_rate: 1.0
 * /icon: turtlebot_bringup...
 * /interactions/interactions: ['turtlebot_bring...
 * /interactions/pairing: True
 * /interactions/rosbridge_address: localhost
 * /interactions/rosbridge_port: 9090
 * /interactions/webserver_address: webapp.robotconce...
 * /mobile_base/base_frame: base_footprint
 * /mobile_base/battery_capacity: 16.5
 * /mobile_base/battery_dangerous: 13.2
 * /mobile_base/battery_low: 14.0
 * /mobile_base/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.6
 * /mobile_base/device_port: /dev/kobuki
 * /mobile_base/odom_frame: odom
 * /mobile_base/publish_tf: True
 * /mobile_base/use_imu_heading: True
 * /mobile_base/wheel_left_joint_name: wheel_left_joint
 * /mobile_base/wheel_right_joint_name: wheel_right_joint
 * /name: turtlebot
 * /robot/name: turtlebot
 * /robot/type: turtlebot
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 5.0
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.13
 * /turtlebot_laptop_battery/acpi_path: /sys/class/power_...
 * /use_sim_time: False
 * /zeroconf/zeroconf/services: [{'domain': 'loca...

NODES
  /zeroconf/
    zeroconf (zeroconf_avahi/zeroconf)
  /
    app_manager (rocon_app_manager/rapp_manager.py)
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    capability_server (capabilities/capability_server)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    interactions (rocon_interactions/interactions_manager.py)
    master (rocon_master_info/master.py)
    mobile_base (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    turtlebot_laptop_battery (laptop_battery_monitor/laptop_battery.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [1876]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [1889]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [1907]
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 1907, exit code -7, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/odroid/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/odroid/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101/robot_state_publisher-2*.log
process[diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [1908]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [1927]
process[mobile_base-5]: started with pid [1931]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [2015]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [2043]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-8]: started with pid [2120]
process[capability_server-9]: started with pid [2148]
process[app_manager-10]: started with pid [2170]
process[master-11]: started with pid [2179]
[WARN] [WallTime: 1432279214.111895] Battery : unable to check laptop battery info [/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full_design || /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design does not exist]
process[interactions-12]: started with pid [2227]
process[zeroconf/zeroconf-13]: started with pid [2258]
[turtlebot_laptop_battery-8] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/odroid/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101/turtlebot_laptop_battery-8*.log
[ INFO] [1432279216.138766005]: Zeroconf: service successfully established [turtlebot][_ros-master._tcp][11311]
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bondpy/bondpy.py:114: SyntaxWarning: The publisher should be created with an explicit keyword argument 'queue_size'. Please see http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers for more information.
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(self.topic, Status)
```

log folder after running contains this:

```
odroid@odroid:~/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101$ ls
app_manager-10-stdout.log           master.log
app_manager-10.log                  mobile_base-5-stdout.log
bumper2pointcloud-7-stdout.log      mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4-stdout.log
capability_server-9-stdout.log      robot_state_publisher-2-stdout.log
capability_server-9.log             roslaunch-odroid-1862.log
cmd_vel_mux-6-stdout.log            roslaunch-odroid-2303.log
diagnostic_aggregator-3-stdout.log  rosout-1-stdout.log
interactions-12-stdout.log          rosout.log
interactions-12.log                 turtlebot_laptop_battery-8-stdout.log
master-11-stdout.log                turtlebot_laptop_battery-8.log
master-11.log
odroid@odroid:~/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101$ cat robot_state_publisher-2-stdout.log
odroid@odroid:~/.ros/log/f6f0c208-0052-11e5-a038-001e06c2b101$
```

Have tried switching to staging, but no newer versions are available. Tried a fresh install on on odroid U3 and get the same error on there.

Have tried reinstalling from scratch, building turtlebot from source, with no success.
Running roswtf on the launch file produces

```
$ roswtf minimal.launch
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
    rosboost_cfg.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 362, in main
    output = lflags(ver, options.lflags.split(','))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 280, in lflags
    s += lib_flags(ver, lib) + " "
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 270, in lib_flags
    lib = find_lib(ver, name)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 240, in find_lib
    raise BoostError('Could not locate library [%s], version %s'%(name, ver))
rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Could not locate library [regex], version (1, 54, 0, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True)"
```

this text is repeated 4 times (From the traceback line, and then prints out what is below and roswtf terminates

=

```
===============================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 1 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /rosout:
   * /rosout
```

googling that gives previous similar errors, but not for regex -eg https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/62 and https://github.com/ros/ros/issues/66

it might be related to those

Tried following this  http://answers.ros.org/question/11155/rospack-ends-with-rosboost_cfgrosboost_cfgboosterror/
as it seems to be the same issue
got this result

```
odroid@odroid:/opt/ros/indigo/share/turtlebot_bringup/launch$ cd
odroid@odroid:~$ export ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME=/usr/share/doc/
odroid@odroid:~$ echo $ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME
/usr/share/doc/
odroid@odroid:~$ ls /usr/share/doc/ | grep boost-regex
libboost-regex-dev
libboost-regex1.54-dev
libboost-regex1.54.0
odroid@odroid:~$ rosboost-cfg --libs regex
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
    rosboost_cfg.main()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 350, in main
    output = libs(ver, options.libs.split(','))
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 286, in libs
    s += find_lib(ver, lib, True) + " "
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 251, in find_lib
    raise BoostError('Could not locate library [%s], version %s in lib directory [%s]'%(name, ver, dir))
rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Could not locate library [regex], version (1, 54, 0, '/usr', '/usr/include', True, True) in lib directory [/usr/share/doc/]"
```

and same error on minimal.launch

changed ROS_BOOST_LIB_DIR_NAME to /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ based on a webpage that I can't remember, but could find again if needed. This got rid of the errors in roswtf minimal.launch, but robot_state_publisher still fails when it is run

testing on a amd64 install roswtf minimal.launch generates the same errors, but minimal.launch runs successfully, so it would appear that was a dead end.

running with gdb trace as requested produces this

```
setting /run_id to 5d69beda-02c0-11e5-9ec8-001e06c2b101
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6778]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [6796]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-3]: started with pid [6798]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [6820]
process[mobile_base-5]: started with pid [6858]
process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [6914]
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [6974]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-8]: started with pid [7040]
process[capability_server-9]: started with pid [7060]
[tcsetpgrp failed in terminal_inferior: Inappropriate ioctl for device]
```

do those messages mean I need to run roslaunch as root ?

note - the turtlebot is not plugged in as I am at home at the moment in case any of those are related to that - launch previously worked with no turtlebot

ok messages are benign https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/223

but means there is nothing printed there that seems to be useful - and presumably as robot_state_publisher isn't crashing now there is no core dump generated ? looking in .ros there is a file called roscore-11311.pid

```
odroid@odroid:~/.ros$ cat roscore-11311.pid
6829odroid@odroid:~/.ros$
```

tried with the screen version, but get

```
odroid@odroid:~$ screen -D -R
Aborted
odroid@odroid:~$
```

when try to look at gdb

tried the screen version again, and it appears to have worked, result in screen is here

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/odroid/ros/devel/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb)
```

but typing bt at gdb prompt gets response No stack

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209686/turtlebot-apt-get-update-has-generated-an-error-on-minimal.launch/) by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1504 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-21**:
Please document the versions of the packages you're running as well as the full console output of what you're running.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-05-22**:
further info - updated raspberry pi, once updated, same error. On VM machine (not ARM) updated still works

turtlebot packages updated on pi (can't list all in comment) turtlebot, turtlebot-bringup, turtlebot-capabilities, turtlebot-description, turtlebot-teleop

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-05-22**:
turtlebot-bringup, turtlebot-capabilities, turtlebot-description, turtlebot-teleop are all version 2.3.11

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-05-24**:
I can confirm it has stopped working on ODROID XU3 as well, I guess it only affects ARM processors. Is there a way to revert to the working version of robot_state_publisher? Need my robot to work real fast

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-25**:
Can you get a gdb backtrace? [tutorial for launching with gdb](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-05-28**:
The gdb backtrace resulted in:
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGBUS, Bus error.
0xb661ac74 in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3

PS. I'm using robot_state_publisher in my own robot, not turtlebot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I have tracked it down - building robot_model from most current source in a workspace stops robot_state_publisher from crashing. Have tried it on a xu3 and a raspberry pi2 and it has worked on both.

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-30**:
Interesting, thanks for tracking that down. I'll have to take a look at why that makes a difference.

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-01**:
weird, I'm still unable to make it work, it always die with error code -7

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-01**:
I installed dependencies for the workspace as well (rosdep install --from-paths src -i -y), so that may pull in something relevant, and assume you have sourced the setup file after building the workspace? I am just using standard turtlebot install, but haven't tested with actual robot yet

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-01**:
Sorry, quite a newbie here, what do you mean by building robot_model, i assume it's for turtlebot? What if I'm using my own robot model for rviz?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-01**:
http://wiki.ros.org/robot_model

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-01**:
robot_model build a robot model from the files you have, it is not the robot model of the robot.

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-02**:
Ok, I've tried rebuilding all of them. Now, the error code has changed from -7 to 127 and still died upon launch

EDIT: Nope, still error -7, and when rosrun robot_state_publisher just to check, it returns Bus error.

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-02**:
I don't know if it's related, but running rviz returns bus error while most people complained about seg fault

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-03**:
It's finally working with the rebuilt robot_model, 1 version before the current one

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-03**:
Can you clarify specifically which version works for you?

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-06-03**:
robot_model release: 1.11.6.

The robot_state_publisher using robot_model release 1.11.7 still failed to launch when I built that robot_model in my workspace

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-03**:
for me
commit 6534424a2 works
commit 3c5521790 works
commit 04f763742 doesn't

do you want me to go further back to see where it stopped working originally ?

**Comment by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) on 2015-08-23**:
I had the same problem on a cubieboard2 - and rebuilding robot_model from source fixed it indeed. Thanks!

**Comment by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on 2015-09-10**:
This did NOT work for me on the Odroid XU3 running Ubuntu 14.04, fully upgraded. See my answer below with my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can confirm that the package ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher_1.10.4-0trusty-20150503-170826-0700_armhf.deb exhibits this problem but the slightly older version does not: ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher_1.10.4-0trusty-20150403-134710-0700_armhf.deb

The crash I get is a segfault -11

```
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 1644, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/linaro/.ros/log/bcc9a036-04c1-11e5-aa48-00037f20a274/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/linaro/.ros/log/bcc9a036-04c1-11e5-aa48-00037f20a274/robot_state_publisher-2*.log
```

I diffed the files and there's very little difference: [image: Imgur]

There's a new version in the pipeline and it has a similar diff: [image: Imgur]

Can you try it? http://54.183.65.232/ubuntu/testing/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher/ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher_1.10.4-0trusty-20150524-130116-0700_armhf.deb

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-05-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cubex](https://answers.ros.org/users/22535/cubex/) on 2015-05-28**:
the link you gave is the new robot state publisher, not the previous version

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-05-28**:
still dies for me, probably for the reason above ;)

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-05-28**:
I tried building robot_state_publisher in a workspace from commit 49bca4e again (had done that previously), and it still crashes (exit code -7, cmd /home/odroid/ros/devel/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher). I think that is as far back as the build you referenced

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-28**:
Here's [the old version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngnogwuzdhgcxs0/ros-indigo-robot-state-publisher_1.10.4-0trusty-20150403-134710-0700_armhf.deb?dl=0) from before the last update. However I think that the problem is not specifically in this package but possibly an ABI issue with dependencies.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-01**:
ros-shadow-fixed has a newer version of robot_model. please try pulling from there.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-06-01**:
The newly synced debians have a rebuilt robot_model built on 5/24 which might be worth testing.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-01**:
ros-shadow-fixed is working for me on odroid c1 - will try it on others as well

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-01**:
only worked on that first one - other 3 boards I have tried not fixed - but overlaying workspace still fixes it

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-02**:
actually the one it did work on had the workspace sourced in .bashrc without that it fails too

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2015-06-04**:
The shadow-fixed one is working for me on Odroid U3.

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-05**:
I'm probably not using shadow fixed properly. tried a total reinstall, reflashed ubuntu, installed ros, switched to shadow fixed, updated apt-get, but on install robot-state-publisher it says already the latest version, either shadow fixed is in sync with main release, or I'm doing something wrong

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-06-05**:
tried dist-upgrade with shadow-fixed, but nothing to upgrade, so I think I am not configuring it properly

**Comment by [rohbotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/23169/rohbotics/) on 2015-07-19**:
Did the fix propagate up into the main ros pool yet?

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-08-03**:
no it looks like they are waiting on another package to release an update first  - just install ed on a new xu4 and go the same issue
https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/109
https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The accepted answer (build `robot_state_publisher` from source) did NOT work for me on Odroid XU3 using fully upgraded Ubuntu 14.04. For me, the real culprit seems to be the `libpcre3` package according to the gdb backtraces.

My workaround is to upgrade the `libpcre3` package (and related `-dev`, `-dbg`, and `libpcrecpp0` packages) with the .deb binaries from Utopic (Ubuntu 14.10).

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182261128/libpcre3_8.35-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182261132/libpcre3-dev_8.35-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182261135/libpcre3-dbg_8.35-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/182261131/libpcrecpp0_8.35-3ubuntu1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libpcre*8.35*.deb
```

After this, the `robot_state_publisher` should run fine, even without compiling it from source.

---

Originally posted by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) with karma: 81 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-09-10**:
@NStiurca That's interesting.
There's also a known issue with rviz and pcre on armhf: http://answers.ros.org/question/212319/rviz-segmentation-fault-on-nvidia-jetson-tk1/

It's possible that recompiling from source simply hides the problem with pcre. That could explain the reproducibility.

**Comment by [NStiurca](https://answers.ros.org/users/393/nstiurca/) on 2015-09-11**:
It may be worth filing a bug report with Ubuntu then since 14.04 is LTS. For my part, I dropped a link to this answer in the question you linked.

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2015-09-12**:
Recompiling robot_state_publisher from source didn't work for me either, but recompiling both robot_state_publisher and the robot_model repo from source did work. I'm yet sure that this is just a bug within libpcre

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2015-09-13**:
looks like the latest release of robot_model removes the direct dependency on libpcre, which looked like it had been added to get round a previous issue.

Compiling the most up to date robot_model from the repo source with these commits was what was working for me, not the 1.11.7 release